# How do I describe even values of the tenths digit of a number?

Tags: single-word-requests

How can I describe the following numbers?

```
0.2
0.4
0.6
0.8
```

Can I call them "even tenths"?

For example:

"If the maximum value in the data set is 1, then the values displayed in the bar graph are the **______**." I am pertaining to the numbers above.

Comment: Typically, these are called "fifths."

Comment: Your question in the text is different from your question in the title. Are you looking for what to call those four numbers? If so, yes they are fifths of a unit. Or are you looking for a way to describe an even first digit after the decimal point (as the title says)? The entire number or the first digit? Why don't you give a sentence showing how you would use the answer **X** that you are looking for?

Comment: FWIW, I would probably just say that the tenths digit (or the tenths place) is even, and not look for a noun for it.

Comment: Better asked on [math.se]

Comment: Hi @Kris. I actually went to that site first, but I can't seem to find a suitable tag.

Comment: We can get help from the mods for the tags. Usually simpler/ basic questions have difficulty finding broad-based tags in any Q&A. If the Q still exists on Math site, show a link here.

Comment: @Kris: I was unable to post my question on Math site. Maybe I could ask this on meta.

Comment: If that was only because you could not find a suitable tag, then you can select *any* tag and ask the mods to edit the tags. Anyway, this Q could be migrated over there.

Comment: @Tatpurusha The argument whether they are actually "tenths" or "fifths" is not much about the English language.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be migrated to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mari-LouA I already flagged this question and I recommended this for deletion. I cannot delete the question myself because it says it already has answers.

Comment: If you ask this on math.stackexchange then you're probably going to get a highly mathematical answer, rather than an english language usage answer.

Answer (score 3):

It just so happens that there is an answer to this very question on the math stack exchange.

[Can decimal numbers be considered “even” or “odd”?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92451/can-decimal-numbers-be-considered-even-or-odd)

Reading through the answers there, I think it's safe to say that a decimal number can **not** be called even (or odd) unless you are prepared to get into some serious math and/or philosophy.

Comment: Ha, save us from serious mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add *even* into your description.
The first place that comes after the decimal point is always just a tenth.

> 0.2 - two tenths, also shown as 2/10 (or one fifth, 1/5)
>
> 0.04 - four (one) hundredths
>
> 0.006 - six (one) thousandths and so on

If your number looked like this - 0.41 - then you would simply state that it is *zero/nought-point-four-one* or *four tenths and one hundredth.*  It is not referred to as an *uneven tenth*.